# Troubles passing Apex superbadge

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I wrote unit tests for Maintenance Request and Maintenance Request helper, positive, negative and bulk cases, but I cannot pass the challenge. Any help will be great, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: In the Developer Console, try using Test > Clear Test Data, followed by Test > Run All, then try validating again, and let us know if that fixed the problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for the reply. I did as you said, but, unfortunately, the result is the same